# Loop through folders/files and replace word

Tags: powershell

Trying to loop through a folders/subfolders that contains multiple html files to find a specific string/word.

Once the powershell script finds it - it will list which files contains the matching words.
Maybe a prompt for the user to replace the word or just  set a variable such as $replaceword = 'test2'

```
$match = "THIS IS A TEST"
#$replacement = Read-Host "Please enter a solution name"
$files = Get-ChildItem -path C:\Users\testfolder -filter *THIS IS A TEST* -Recurse
$files
    Sort-Object -Descending -Property { $_.FullName }
    #Rename-Item -newname { $_.name -replace $match, $replacement } -force
$files = Get-ChildItem -path C:\Users\testfolder -include *.html -Recurse
foreach($file in $files)
{
    ((Get-Content $file.fullname) -creplace $match)
read-host -prompt "Done! Press any key to close."
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to replace file names or the content of files on a match?

Comment: a word/string inside of these html files.. not a file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following, which will replace ***matching content*** of `.html` files in the `C:\Users\testfolder` directory structure:

```
$matchString = 'THIS IS A TEST'
$replaceString = 'New String'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\testfolder' -filter *.html -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $matchFound = $false
    $output = switch -regex -file $file.fullname {
        $matchString { $_ -replace $matchString,$replaceString
                       $matchFound = $true
        }
        default { $_ }
    }
    if ($matchFound) {
        $output | Set-Content $file.fullname
    }
}
```

If you really want an interactive prompt to replace the string, you can move the `$replaceString` to a different place within the script logic and add the `Read-Host` command.

**Explanation:**

The top of the script contains `$matchString` (the case-sensitive string you want to match) and `$replaceString` (the replacement string).

`Get-ChildItem` uses `-Filter` to find all files that end with the HTML extension. The `-Recurse` switch is used to search all subdirectories from the path.

The switch statement is used in favor of `Get-Content` because it typically performs faster. We only want to overwrite a file when a match is found. `$matchFound` begins as `$false` and will become `$true` when a match is found.

`-creplace` is used here since your source code used it. `-creplace` performs a case-sensitive regex match and replace.

---

**Interactive Alternative:**

For an interactive element, you can ask the user to enter the replacement string each time a match is found. This simply moves the `$replaceString` assignment inside of the `switch` statement and lists the file that contains the match.

```
$matchString = 'THIS IS A TEST'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\testfolder' -filter *.html -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $matchFound = $false
    $output = switch -regex -file $file.fullname {
        $matchString { $replaceString = Read-Host -Prompt "$($file.fullname) contains '$matchString'. Enter your replacement string"
                       $_ -replace $matchString,$replaceString
                       $matchFound = $true
        }
        default { $_ }
    }
    if ($matchFound) {
        $output | Set-Content $file.fullname
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to run the script above - but did not work. It doesnt even check the folders

Comment: It works on PowerShell v5. It recurses c:\users\testfolder for all *.html files.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say it does not check the folders? If `c:\users\testfolder` is not your starting point, then the code needs to be updated with the correct path.

Comment: It is my starting point, but inside of c:users\testfolder there are html files and also subfolders as well that contains html files

Comment: Admin - it works, thanks for the help. Now for the matchString - how can i avoid casesensitive -  ? $matchstring = "TEST"   won't find  = 'test'  as an example

Comment: @user9191 I removed the case-sensitivity. This was done by removing `-casesensitive` from the `switch` statement and changing `-creplace` to `-replace`.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this, it's a simpler example:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\path\here -Recurse 
$matchString = 'THIS IS A TEST'
$replacementString = 'replace'

foreach ($i in $files){
    #Check its a file
    if (!$i.PSIsContainer){
        #Check the name contains the $matchString
        if ($i.Name -match $matchString){

            Set-Content -Path $i.FullName -Value $replacementString -Confirm:$true
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if I've misunderstood what you want :)

Comment: Its not even checking the folders - I have a directory with multiple subfolders that contains html files.

Comment: What do you mean? Did you change the path in the `Get-ChildItem` command?

Comment: Yes I did change the path